# Tetrachoric correlation and Fortran style format

Tags: matrix

I am trying to get a tetrachoric correlation matrix to perform a factor analysis on dichotomous variables. I have been guided to a number of programs to calculate the matrix. These have been very helpful in aiding my understanding about the correlations. However I have not been able to get them to run with my data. I have no problem with the examples they provide. so I am wondering if it has to do with my data file and the input data format that I prescribe.

Tetcorr from JS fleming, The program asks for fortran style format codes.

I have the following data (just a section of it, there are actually 142 cases but the number of variables are the same)

1 1 1 2 1 1

1 2 1 2 2 1

1 1 2 2 2 1

2 1 1 2 2 1

The input format I have prescribed is (6F2.0). the files have been .txt files or dat files (I have tried a number of different ways)

For TetMatt (Ubersax)I just get an error message saying that it cannot read the input file.

Has anyone had experience with these programs and can give me any advise. Or is there another another way to get the correlation matrix that you could recommend?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The 'F' in your input format indicates a decimal number (ie. one with a decimal point). Your input is Integer, try (6I2), see if that works...

Comment: Thanks for responding Neal. I tried it but unfortunately didn't work. I will keep on trying various options. Sarah